# removing a navbar from a jQuery Mobile header does not resize header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar in a header I want to make optional, i.e. to be able to show/hide it depending on context.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
   ...header stuff...
   <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
     ..navbar stuff
   </div>
</div>
```

This looks and works fine. However, if I hide the navbar using a jQuery .hide() the navbar vanishes but the header does not vertically resize, leaving a gap before the remaining content.

Recreated here: https://jsfiddle.net/needlethread/wsuxxokx/

How to do/workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding $(window).resize() will do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='tt_view_sel']").on('change', function () {
        view = $(this).val();
        if (view == "data") {
            $(".tt_toolhdr").hide();
            **$(window).resize();**
        } else {
            $(".tt_toolhdr").show();
            **$(window).resize();**
        }
    });
});
```